# while doing Json.encodePrettily(object) in vertx null values are also getting included

Tags: json, vertx-httpclient

while doing Json.encodePrettily(object) in vertx null values are also getting included.

so need to know how we can configure it to avoid null values in response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

io.vertx.core.json is implemented using jackson fasterxml so vertx internally uses jackson fasterxml library. So unless explicitly required there is no need to use any other json library with vertx.

so to avoid same we can use following

```
Json.prettyMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add
`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` at the top of your model class.

Answer (score 0):

`Json.prettyMapper` is deprecated. You can remove the null values manually. with a lambda:

```java
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

MyCustomDtoClass body = new MyCustomDtoClass(...)

JsonObject jsonBody = new JsonObject(Json.encode(body))
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
    .collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue),
            JsonObject::new
        )
    );
```